Extra indentation added in enumitem after item 10
I am creating a legal document with numbered clauses. To get this I am using an enumitem. I have the desired format and indentation I want, but when the number of items reaches 10 or higher, extra indentation is added to the item text, of items in all levels, not just the lowest level. An example is shown below:
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}

% Define the environment for legal clauses
\newlist{legal}{enumerate}{3}

\setlist[legal,1]{%
  label=\arabic*,
  ref=\arabic*,
  left= 0pt .. 3em,
  align=left,
  itemsep=0pt,%0.5em,
}

\setlist[legal,2]{%
  label=\arabic{legali}.\arabic*,
  ref=\arabic{legali}.\arabic*,
  left= -3em .. 0pt,
  align=left,
  itemsep=0pt,%0.5em,
}

\setlist[legal,3]{%
  label=\arabic{legali}.\arabic{legalii}.\arabic*,
  ref=\arabic{legali}.\arabic{legalii}.\arabic*,
  left= 0pt .. 3em,
  align=left,
  itemsep=0.5em,
}


\begin{document}
\begin{legal}
    \item This is the first clause.
    \item This Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent porttitor arcu luctus, imperdiet urna iaculis, mattis eros. Pellentesque iaculis odio vel nisl ullamcorper, nec faucibus ipsum molestie. Sed dictum nisl non aliquet porttitor. Etiam vulputate arcu dignissim, finibus sem et, viverra nisl. Aenean luctus congue massa, ut laoreet metus ornare in. Nunc fermentum nisi imperdiet lectus tincidunt vestibulum at ac elit.
    \begin{legal}
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent porttitor arcu luctus, imperdiet urna iaculis, mattis eros. Pellentesque iaculis odio vel nisl ullamcorper, nec faucibus ipsum molestie. Sed dictum nisl non aliquet porttitor. Etiam vulputate arcu dignissim, finibus sem et, viverra nisl. Aenean luctus congue massa, ut laoreet metus ornare in. Nunc fermentum nisi imperdiet lectus tincidunt vestibulum at ac elit.
        \item This is another sub-clause of the second clause.
        \begin{legal}
            \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque lobortis justo enim, a condimentum massa tempor eu. Ut quis nulla a quam pretium eleifend nec eu nisl. Nam cursus porttitor eros, sed luctus ligula convallis quis.
            \item This is another sub-sub-clause of the second sub-clause.
        \end{legal}
        \item This is a third sub-clause of the second clause.
    \end{legal}
    \item This is a clause. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    \item This is a clause. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    \item This is a clause. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    \item This is a clause. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    \item This is a clause. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    \item This is a clause. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    \item This is a clause. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    \item This is a clause. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    \item This is a clause. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    \begin{legal}
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent porttitor arcu luctus, imperdiet urna iaculis, mattis eros. Pellentesque iaculis odio vel nisl ullamcorper, nec faucibus ipsum molestie. Sed dictum nisl non aliquet porttitor. Etiam vulputate arcu dignissim, finibus sem et, viverra nisl. Aenean luctus congue massa, ut laoreet metus ornare in. Nunc fermentum nisi imperdiet lectus tincidunt vestibulum at ac elit.
        \item This is another sub-clause of the second clause.
        \begin{legal}
            \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque lobortis justo enim, a condimentum massa tempor eu. Ut quis nulla a quam pretium eleifend nec eu nisl. Nam cursus porttitor eros, sed luctus ligula convallis quis.
            \item This is another sub-sub-clause of the second sub-clause.
        \end{legal}
        \item This is a third sub-clause of the second clause.
    \end{legal}
\end{legal}
\end{document}


How can I prevent this extra indentation form item 10 onwards?
Perhaps worth noting that the idea for how this works was given to me in another question

as the documention notes, it relies internally on widest, so you should set something like widest*=99

You need to set the widest parameter for the top level list:
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}

% Define the environment for legal clauses
\newlist{legal}{enumerate}{3}

\setlist[legal,1]{%
  label=\arabic*,
  ref=\arabic*,
  left= 0pt .. 3em,
  align=left,
  itemsep=0pt,%0.5em,
  widest=100
}

\setlist[legal,2]{%
  label=\arabic{legali}.\arabic*,
  ref=\arabic{legali}.\arabic*,
  left= -3em .. 0pt,
  align=left,
  itemsep=0pt,%0.5em,
}

\setlist[legal,3]{%
  label=\arabic{legali}.\arabic{legalii}.\arabic*,
  ref=\arabic{legali}.\arabic{legalii}.\arabic*,
  left= 0pt .. 3em,
  align=left,
  itemsep=0.5em,
}


\begin{document}
\begin{legal}
    \item This is the first clause.
    \item This Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent porttitor arcu luctus, imperdiet urna iaculis, mattis eros. Pellentesque iaculis odio vel nisl ullamcorper, nec faucibus ipsum molestie. Sed dictum nisl non aliquet porttitor. Etiam vulputate arcu dignissim, finibus sem et, viverra nisl. Aenean luctus congue massa, ut laoreet metus ornare in. Nunc fermentum nisi imperdiet lectus tincidunt vestibulum at ac elit.
    \begin{legal}
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent porttitor arcu luctus, imperdiet urna iaculis, mattis eros. Pellentesque iaculis odio vel nisl ullamcorper, nec faucibus ipsum molestie. Sed dictum nisl non aliquet porttitor. Etiam vulputate arcu dignissim, finibus sem et, viverra nisl. Aenean luctus congue massa, ut laoreet metus ornare in. Nunc fermentum nisi imperdiet lectus tincidunt vestibulum at ac elit.
        \item This is another sub-clause of the second clause.
        \begin{legal}
            \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque lobortis justo enim, a condimentum massa tempor eu. Ut quis nulla a quam pretium eleifend nec eu nisl. Nam cursus porttitor eros, sed luctus ligula convallis quis.
            \item This is another sub-sub-clause of the second sub-clause.
        \end{legal}
        \item This is a third sub-clause of the second clause.
    \end{legal}
    \item This is a clause. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    \item This is a clause. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    \item This is a clause. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    \item This is a clause. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    \item This is a clause. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    \item This is a clause. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    \item This is a clause. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    \item This is a clause. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    \item This is a clause. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    \begin{legal}
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent porttitor arcu luctus, imperdiet urna iaculis, mattis eros. Pellentesque iaculis odio vel nisl ullamcorper, nec faucibus ipsum molestie. Sed dictum nisl non aliquet porttitor. Etiam vulputate arcu dignissim, finibus sem et, viverra nisl. Aenean luctus congue massa, ut laoreet metus ornare in. Nunc fermentum nisi imperdiet lectus tincidunt vestibulum at ac elit.
        \item This is another sub-clause of the second clause.
        \begin{legal}
            \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque lobortis justo enim, a condimentum massa tempor eu. Ut quis nulla a quam pretium eleifend nec eu nisl. Nam cursus porttitor eros, sed luctus ligula convallis quis.
            \item This is another sub-sub-clause of the second sub-clause.
        \end{legal}
        \item This is a third sub-clause of the second clause.
    \end{legal}
\end{legal}
\end{document}


